# FBSDKLoginManager token with email address

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make registration in my iOS app through facebook SDK

I am using FBSDKLoginManager for Login in to facebook from that I am getting AccessToken which I have verified.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=tokenstring
```

I got the name and Id in response but I need to get email also for registration on **Qiuckblox**.

I have downloaded **q-municate** app(based quickblox.com) from github and checked token.
I have same tokens but result is different. How come?
Maybe I should set some settings in facebook?

```
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[login logOut];

[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email", @"public_profile", @"user_friends"]
             fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        // Process error
        NSLog(@"%@",error.localizedDescription);
    }
    else if (result.isCancelled) {
        // Handle cancellations
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%@",result.token.tokenString);

        if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
            NSLog(@"Granted all permission");
            if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location ,friends ,hometown , friendlists"}] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                    if (!error) {
                        NSLog(@"%@",result);
                    }
                }];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not granted");
        }
    }
}];
```

here screenshots:

http://screencast.com/t/9KNK9HIb

http://screencast.com/t/BDsfYVZi

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly enumerate all the fields you want:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=id,name,email,gender&access_token=<access_token>`

Answer (score 0):

```
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"}]

     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error)
         {
             NSLog(@"results:%@",result);

             NSString *email = [result objectForKey:@"email"];
          }
```

Change like this